# Can't properly plot a bar for float numbers using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I've got 50 float number in a variable named `v`, each one are related to a range between 0 to 10000 with the step of 200.

A sample of the numbers:

```
print(v[0:4])
```

```
[1.90432656848e-05, 0.0014909867739, 0.00886048514416, 0.0131592904038]
```

I need to display them as a bar chart:

```
p = plt.bar(range(0, 10000, 200), v)
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

However I'm able to show them using `plot`:

```
p = plt.plot(range(0, 10000, 200), v)
```

[image]

So what's that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the width of the bars. The default width is `0.8`, so with a step of `200` this is just too thin to display.

You can adjust the width of the bars with:

`p = plt.bar(range(0, 10000, 200), v, width=100)`